# ImageView won't hide or clear image on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, imageview

I've been working with android this days (iOS Developer), and I am unable to clear a ImageView. I've tried everything! Literally! I take a photo with my Camera instance, I am able to place the image in the image view and then when I want to remove it. It just freezes. However, the other UIView elements altered in the code below, work normally. (So I guess the UI Thread is working just fine).

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("DEFAULTS", "Back to Defaults");

            processedTranslations = 0;
            totalTranslations = 0;

            nextIsProcessFaces = false;
            nextIsFinish = false;
            currentImage = null;

            imagePreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imagePreview.setImageDrawable(null);
            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(null);
            imagePreview.setImageURI(null);
            imagePreview.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imagePreview.setImageResource(0);
            imagePreview.destroyDrawingCache();
            imagePreview.invalidate();

            loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            captureButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

And here is where I assign the resource to the ImageView (This block gets executed before the previous block) (Maybe the error is that it is nested in another thread? It is not released when the other thread tries to edit that imageView?)

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bitmap bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blockData, 0, blockData.length);
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(90);
                        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMapImage , 0, 0, bitMapImage .getWidth(), bitMapImage .getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        imagePreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                        imagePreview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                        imagePreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

I know this appears to be a really novice question (And a very repeated question) but I've tried all of the answers in similar questions (As you can see in my code.) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you are working with the wrong `ImageView`. You already have `loadingView` and `captureButton` from somewhere else. Why are you calling `findViewById()` here? Perhaps that is returning a different `ImageView` than the one that you are supposed to be modifying.

Comment: Is it android.widget.ImageView; ? @CommonsWare

Comment: No, I mean the wrong `ImageView` instance, not the wrong `ImageView` class.

Comment: I was just testing. I thought maybe the resource pointer became corrupted somewhere along the code execution. However, without that findView it is still broken @CommonsWare

Comment: Well, `setVisibility(View.GONE)` works for everybody else to temporarily remove a view from the view hierarchy (so it is not rendered and takes up no space). If that is not working, and you are not crashing with a `NullPointerException`, then you must be calling `setVisibility()` on the wrong `ImageView` instance. I suggest that you create a scrap Android project, put an `ImageView` widget in it, call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on it in `onCreate()`, and confirm that the `ImageView` indeed is gone. Then, figure out how to get to the right `ImageView` widget in your main project.

Comment: where do you assign the resource for imagePreview? Assuming this is the one you want to get rid off.

Comment: @AndroidNFC Edited the question. Maybe is because the ImageView is nested in another thread? Is it released automatically?

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe it is a multithread error? Check edited Question

Comment: Well, that second block of code would undo everything from your first block of code. So, if your second block of code executes after the first block, you would not see any effects of the first block.

Comment: @CommonsWare the second block is where I Assing the resource, it is called before the first block. (The second block works fine!)

Comment: but does the Thread end after you jump on another Thread. If you have two threads running in background and assigning some values to same Views, could be what's bothering the program?

Comment: `(This block gets executed before the previous block)` and your comment `Maybe it is a multithread error? ` are confusing (no indication in code snippets that you're multithreading). Are you using other Threads to perform these tasks, other than the UI Thread? If so, why? Also can you guarantee, if multithreading, that the code is executing in the correct or expected order? Add some logging perhaps to double check?